# How to make a discord bot command list with python

Tags: discord.py

How to add command list like fredboat here with python
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bB5WR.png)

Comment: Discord.py does support slash/application commands and many more. It's just not on pypi yet but will be very soon. You can install the 2.0 version with `pip install -U git+https://github.com/Rapptz/discord.py`. @Nik

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

when creating slash commands it will automatically appear like **FredBoat**, you don't need to add anything to make it appear, to make slash commands use interactions.py or something similar, thanks.